# Sending email to all type of email address in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I want to `send email` to my users and it works fine. but because of some reason some of users can't receive my emails, I guess because their `email's format` is more than 3 syllables `(a@b.c.r)`
but the others whom can receive my emails has this email format: `a@b.c`
now how should I change the code, in order to `send emails to every type of emails`.

here is code:

```
  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.Subject = "Account Information";
        //  msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(TextBox2.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("waag@waag.ir");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        SmtpClient mailsender = new SmtpClient();

        mailsender.Host = "SmtpClient.waag.ir";

        mailsender.Port = 587;
        mailsender.EnableSsl = true;
        mailsender.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("waag@waag.ir", "classaspnet");
      //  mailsender loginInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("waag@waag.ir", "classaspnet");

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        msg.Body = bodyMsg.ToString();
```

and here is web config file code:

```
  <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="waag@goldentest.ir">
        <network host="mail.waag.ir" port="25" userName="waag@waag.ir" password="*****"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Does you code throws an error or email just doesn't reach recipients?

Comment: it doesn't have any error... the email doesn't reach!

Comment: By the way: the actual Send call is missing in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your code - either a supplied email address is valid or not. You can't create a function that turns an invalid email address into a valid one.

There are many reasons why some of your users may not receive your email. I name just a few of them:

- Email address does not exists
- Email inbox is full
- Your email was marked as spam
- temporary network errors
- The email Address is not in a valid format

For the most of them, your smtp server can deliver the mail to the foreign mail server, so you don't get an exception while sending the mail.

A few minutes, hours or even days later the foreign mail server sends a delivery failure notice email to the sender email address with the specific failure reason.

Comment: thank you for your reply,but i test it for 3 different email and it doesn't work for none of them. but for all other emails it works(Yahoo, Gmail....) in addition  the emails are also correct and valid. Is it possible that the email receive days latter?

Comment: Yes of cause its possible. Mailservers retry to deliver an email a few times with increasing delays when non permanent errors occur.

Comment: none the reasons that you mention above didn't occur for me. Do any idea or solution?